# Lost reputation after clearing browser history

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I had to clear my browser history in order to fix a problem with another web site. Now I have lost all reputation on SE and SO, not allowed to comment.  Could someone explain what happened and how it might be fixed?

Comment: Most likely, you have two accounts. This one maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/users/5732537/edstevens Probably should merge them.

Comment: Two accounts... looks like it.  And checking my password keeper, I see that I have two different sign-ons.  Looking at my profile - the one I am currently logged on with, and the "other" one that you linked to ... both show the same alias of 'Edstevens', but neither show the acutal userid (email address) used to log on.  And I see no button to log off.  So how do we merge? How do we move forward from here?

Comment: See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) from the help center.

Comment: Follow the instructions here --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Have filed the form from the link. Thanks.